# Zabbix - how to lower the unsupported item refresh interval

Tags: api, docker, zabbix

I have a container which is runnig zabbix_web and has everything it needs to work properly (zabbix_server and zabbix_web). In a different container I have tests which create zabbix items and perform different checks on them everything through zabbix API. I need to be able to lower the unsupported item resresh interval for tests to be more reliable and I have no idea how to do it. It can be easily done through zabbix web GUI though.

Answer (score 0):

I've spent some time looking for this in Zabbix API and there is no trace of it (up to version 4.4).

So, only option how to change the value other then using web UI is to execute SQL command directly against zabbix database.

Change unsupported item refresh interval to e.g. 10s:

```
UPDATE `config` SET `refresh_unsupported` = '10s' WHERE `configid` = '1';
```

This can get executed on zabbix server from command line or via docker exec. Connection to database depends on whether you use MySQL or PostgreSQL as your DB backend.

Answer (score 0):

Administration -> General -> Other -> Refresh unsupported items

[image]